# Where to find a list of genes coding for protein in human

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression, rna-sequencing

I have raw read counts extracted by htseq from STAR alignment

I have both data with both Ensembl IDs and gene symbols, but I need only a latest list of protein coding genes in human; I googled but I did not find

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and *explicitly* indicate what research they've already done (e.g., what search terms), what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit your ensembl IDs to biomart, and get the "gene biotype".  "protein-coding" is one of the options there.